# How to record voice message and send the voice message to phone number using Twilio?

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, twilio-api

I want to record the voice message from view side and send the voice message to phone number using `Twilio`.

I am using `Laravel PHP` framework. I have already implemented to send the text message to phone number by `Twilio`.

Comment: No @AniketSahrawat I just wanted to know the procedure and which documentation is good?

Comment: The Doc which you have shared, I have already gone through it and implemented the text messaging feature from it. If you have something relevant to voice message feature then only share some relevant document if possible.
For reference you can use this link:
(https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/recording)

In Above link how we store the voice message i.e $recording_sid

Answer (score 1):

As i am getting your problem is first you need to record a message and then that recorded message should be sent using twilio.
So, first you need to record the message and store it on your server or S3 bucket or whatever you are using for storage. And pass that url to your Twilio.

Secondly, you need to send that recorded message as an MMS(Multimedia message) using twilio. For that your ‘to’ and ‘from’ numbers should be capable of sending out MMS messages, you can check that on your twilio account.
For MMS sending in php check this out : https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/how-to-send-sms-messages-in-php#sign-up-for-a-twilio-account

Comment: Thanks for the update. I will check and let you know.

Comment: I am able to send the voice call not message.